# proof $f(x) = \frac{x}{(1+x)}$ is subadditive.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Proof that $f$ sucht that  $f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ defined as

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{(1+x)}$$ is subadditive.

That is, proof that $f(x + y) \le f(x) + f(y)$

I already proved that it is a monotonically non-decreasing function and that $f(0) = 0$

Any suggestions?

I need to prove that to apply it as a lemma for another theorem.

Comment: What have you tried? Observing that $f(x)=1-\frac1{1+x}$ can help a bit.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bx%2By%7D%7B1%2Bx%2By%7D%20%5Cle%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B1%2Bx%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B1%2Bx%7D%24

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this can be shown directly since the domain is the set of non-negative reals as follows,

$f(x+y)=\frac{x+y}{1+x+y} = \frac{x}{1+x+y} + \frac{y}{1+x+y} \leq \frac{x}{1+x} + \frac{y}{1+y} = f(x)+f(y)$

where the last inequality holds since $x$ and $y$ are non-negative implies that $1+x+y \geq 1+x$ and $1+x+y \geq 1+y$.

Answer (score 1):

let be $x,y>0$

observe that $\frac{x}{1+x+y} \le \frac{x}{1+x}$

also that $\frac{y}{1+x+y} \le \frac{y}{1+y}$

Therefore
$\frac{x}{1+x+y} + \frac{y}{1+x+y}  \le \frac{x}{1+x} + \frac{y}{1+y}$

but $\frac{x}{1+x+y} + \frac{y}{1+x+y} = \frac{x + y}{1+x+y}$

Then $f(x + y) \le f(x) + f(y)$

■